# Proof of $\mathbb{E}_{\vartheta_0}|\xi_t|^p<Ct^{p/2}$ for $\xi_t$ Gaussian process with mean 0

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, moment-problem

I currently read paper [2], where, in Chapter 2, one shows that $Y_t-y_t(\vartheta_0)=\varepsilon \xi_t$, where $\xi_t$ is a Gaussian process with $\mathbb{E}_{\vartheta_0}\xi_t=0$. Now, they claim that for every $p>0$ it holds that $$\mathbb{E}_{\vartheta_0}|\xi_t|^p<Ct^{p/2}.$$

Why does this inequality hold? The author names [1] as reference and the only Theorem in that book going into that direction is Lemma 4.11 which states that $\mathbb{E}(\int_0^t f(s,\omega)dW_s)^{2m}\leq K^{2m}t^m(2m-1)!!$ for $W$ a Wiener process and $|f(t,\omega)|<K$ a bounded function. But in my opinion this result is not applicable here. Do you have any other idea on how to show this result?

References:
[1] *Statistics of Random Processes*, Liptser & Shiryaev, 2nd ed. 
[2] *On parameter estimation of the hidden Gaussian process in perturbed SDE*, Kutoyants, Zhou, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09750.pdf

Comment: Does $\xi_t$ have variance $t$? In that case $\xi_t$ has same distribution as $\sqrt t \xi$ where $\xi \sim N(0,1)$ and the inequality is now obvious.

Comment: I don't think so. Earlier, one has shown that $Y_t-y_t(\vartheta_0)=\varepsilon \int_0^t b(s) \frac{A(\vartheta_0,t)}{A(\vartheta_0,s)}dV_s$, where $b$ and $A$ are some deterministic functions and $V_t$ a Wiener process. Since an Itô integral with deterministic integrand is Gaussian, one can write $Y_t-y_t(\vartheta_0)=\varepsilon \xi_t$ with $\xi_t$ being an Gaussian process. Hence, $Var(\xi_t)=\int_0^tb(s)^2 \frac{A(\vartheta_0,t)^2}{A(\vartheta_0,s)^2}ds$ as far as I understand